# Exemplo de utilização - máscara angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

Eu tenho este dois campos, telefone e cep, onde gostaria de colocar máscara, mas como comecei a utilizar angular a pouco tempo, ainda não sei, e não achei nada explicativo na internet, que me ajudasse.

```
  <mat-form-field class="input-full-widthmetade">
        <input #telefone="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fornecedor.telefone" matInput placeholder="Telefone"
            id="telefone" name="telefone">
    </mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="input-full-widthmedade">
    <input #cep="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fornecedor.cep" matInput placeholder="CEP"
        id="cep" name="cep">
</mat-form-field>
```

Como faço para colocar máscara nestes inputs ?
Obrigado.

Comment: Utiliza algum component a parte pra Angular, tem um monte para fazer máscara.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O **[NgxMask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)** é uma biblioteca interessante para máscaras.

**Instalação:**

> npm install --save ngx-mask

**Na importação do teu módulo:**

```
NgxMaskModule.forRoot()
```

**No teu componente ficaria assim:**

```
<mat-form-field class="input-full-widthmetade">
        <input #telefone="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fornecedor.telefone" matInput placeholder="Telefone" id="telefone" name="telefone" mask="(00) 00000-0000">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="input-full-widthmedade">
        <input #cep="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fornecedor.cep" matInput placeholder="CEP" id="cep" name="cep" mask="00000-000">
</mat-form-field>
```

A quantidade de zeros são a quantidade de dígitos numéricos que é possível inserir no campo.

Aconselho-te também a utilizar o formControl para formulários reativos.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Matheus.